# Need to Run a Background request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a Synchronize Scenario in my application to add to the JMeter Script.

Scenario : Sync request is processing on each and every 60 seconds. I need to run this sync request simultaneously while other request are running. Important thing is I need to get the authorization tokens and User ID kind of stuffs from the Login request.

I have created separate thread groups and added sync request in 2nd thread group. added a while loop to the 2nd thread group. This while loop waiting for "login=true". I got the access tokens to the next thread group using props in JMeter. Then I add a loop to send the sync request.

But this not working correctly when running the loops. if loop count is 5 then there should have 5 request for 1 user. but user details duplicating when running the loops.

How can I fix this. Is there an another way to do this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you somehow messed with "loops", it's hard to say anything without seeing your Thread Group configuration.

To avoid any confusion personally I would:

1. Get rid of all "loops" and used [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to run this "synchronize" request forever.
2. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) for passing the authentication data from the main Thread Group
3. When the main Thread Group ends I would go for [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) to stop "synchronize" thread group

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there way to add multiple variables to same Inter Thread communication post processor?

Comment: and other thing is, How can I send a user wise sync request with 1 minute gap without a loop?